# Does the Answer Look Certain?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *The curious obtain a desire, 
>  To draw me back from the glass. 
>  Remove the obvious liar, 
>  To find me in first class. 
>  
>  But before you play the third, 
>  You must take out the sharpest wedge. 
>  Then join the two and reword, 
>  To know why I might hide the ledge. 
>  
>  I usually hang in a pair, 
>  And obscure a view when closed. 
>  Covered with strands of hair, 
>  I can make both sides exposed. 
>  
>  Decoration is my destiny, 
>  With other purposes too; 
>  For example, some prefer privacy, 
>  Or to not let the day come through.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

I feel like the second half might give it away, but I am willing to risk it — I don't want this riddle to be too *opaque*.

Comment: @downvoter may you please explain why you downvoted? Did I do something wrong or did you not like the riddle (because this might not be your taste)? I don't care about reputation — I just want to do what is right by the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> Window Curtains?

Reasoning:
The curious obtain a desire, 
To draw me back from the glass. 
Remove the obvious liar, 
To find me in first class.

> If you want to see outside, you draw them back

But before you play the third, 
You must take out the sharpest wedge. 
Then join the two and reword, 
To know why I might hide the ledge.

> I don't know much about this one, but window curtains are sometimes so long that they hide the ledge of the window

I usually hang in a pair, 
And obscure a view when closed. 
Covered with strands of hair, 
I can make both sides exposed.

> They usually hang in pairs, and block the view. They are usually made of a material that feels like it has small "hairs" on both sides.

Decoration is my destiny, 
With other purposes too; 
For example, some prefer privacy, 
Or to not let the day come through.

> They are usually meant for decoration, although some people use them so people on the outside can not see the inside.

Also:

> The title is "Doesn't the Answer look Certain?" and "Certain" sort of sounds like "Curtain"

And:

> The writer says they don't want the riddle to be too opaque; Ideally, window curtains should not be opaque

Comment: You got most of the reasonings correct. [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Gung vapyhqrf gur nafjre!$]$ Unfortunately, I have reached my daily voting limit, so I have to wait $22$ hours before I can upvote. The explanation of the "sides" were great, but note: the line under the riddle is also a clue. :)

Comment: Is there a better reasoning for the second stanza?

Comment: You did not provide $100\%$ accurate reasonings, but one of these days, I will offer a bounty reward to the user who can solve for the first half of the riddle. Other than that, congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: Can you tell me which part is wrong?

Comment: The explanation for my first half is wrong, (except what you said about the [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)[yrqtr bs gur jvaqbj.])